# Why does puts() function gives me a heart symbol?

Tags: c, arrays, string, output, codeblocks

I was trying to figure out that how a string with a known size can be filled with single characters. Then I wrote this simple code for a bigger problem that I have
 (*dynamic filling of a string with unknown size*)
. When I tried to compile and run this code I encountered a problem which output had a heart symbol! and I don't know where it comes from.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char str[3];
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
        str[i]=getc(stdin);
    }
    puts(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: In C `char` strings are really called ***null terminated*** *byte strings*. That "null terminated" part is important. If you don't have it in a string then all string function will go out of bounds in their search for it, and you will have *undefined behavior* which makes your program *ill-formed* and invalid.

Comment: @Some programmer dude_Thank you. Why doesn't  it skip the extra input ? I know that indexes are 0,1,2 and index-2 is null terminated. If I input stack why it doesn't skip ack ?

Comment: But you *don't* terminate the string in `str`, you read three characters and put them into the array. If you want to read three characters the array needs to be *four* characters large, with the last element being the terminator character (which you explicitly need to initialize as such).

Comment: @ Some programmer dude_You're right.

Comment: Or, maybe the runtime just likes you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`C` strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) are sequences of chars terminated by the [`null` character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) (i.e. the character with code `0`). It can be expressed as `'\0'`, `'\x0'` or simply `0`.

Your code fills `str` with three chars but fails to produce the `null` terminator. Accordingly, [`puts()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts) prints whatever characters it finds in memory until it reaches the first `null` character.

Your code exposes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It can do anything and it's not its fault.

In order to fix it you have to make sure the string ends with the `null` terminating character:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    // Make room for 3 useful chars and the null terminator
    char str[4];
    // Read three chars
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
        str[i] = getc(stdin);
    }
    // Add the null terminator for strings
    str[3] = 0;

    puts(str);
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**

As @JeremyP notes in a comment, if the file you read from (`stdin`) ends before the code reads `3` characters, `fgetc()` will return [`EOF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) (End Of File) characters that are also funny non-printable characters that makes you wonder where they came from.

The correct way to write this code is to check if the input file reached its EOF ([`feof()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof)) before reading from it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    // Make room for 3 useful chars and the null terminator
    char str[4];
    // Read at most three chars
    for(i = 0; i < 3 && !feof(stdin); i ++) {
        str[i] = getc(stdin);
    }
    // Add the null terminator for strings
    str[i] = 0;

    puts(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And waht if I don't bring 'str[3] = 0' into my code ?

Comment: If you don't add `str[3] = 0;` then you are in the same situation as before. You have 3 characters set by `getc()` and the fourth one is what happens to be in memory when the code is executed; a leftover from some other code that executed before. `str` is a local variable; it is not initialized with anything when it is allocated.

Comment: Your code is still incorrect. `getc()` returns `int`  so that it can return `EOF` when end of file is encountered. As things stand, if the file is shorter than three characters, the buffer will be filled up with `(char)EOF` characters, probably `0xff`.

Comment: @JeremyP I agree.

Comment: @Ceeker are you talking about leaving the statement `str[3] = 0;` out? It is undefined behaviour (UB). UB doesn't exclude correct behaviour. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Maybe it always works on your computer and crashes on a different computer, OS, compiler, version of the same compiler etc. It can, as well, apparently work but in fact it could have hidden effects you may notice only later.

Comment: @axiac I hadn't considered that :) .Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in c need to be null terminated so it could be that you forgot to add a `'\0'` character to the end of str. The reason the heart symbol shows up would be that when puts() tries to write out a string it keeps reading the next character in memory until it reaches a null terminator, `'\0'`. Since it doesn't encounter one it just continues reading into memory and happens to find the heart symbol I'd guess. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you dear Nicholas.

Comment: _it could be that you forgot to add a '\0'_, no, it's not _it could be_, he __really__ forgot to add the `\0` character.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, I was just trying to be polite.